Jquery : How to prevent click event as long as css transform translate is in progress?
I create my own datepicker .
Each time I click on year, month, day, hour and min window my div moves/slides from left to right by 300px.
Same action is produced when I click on the arrow left to go back in selection.
The translation works fine if I use as normal, but if I don't wait for the translation to finish, the container doesn't reach its final position.
I try to use e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation() and on.('transitionEnd') but that's not the good functions.
I tried to use transitionEnd as wrapper of click event :
$(document).on('transitionend MSTransitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd','#selector',function(f){});
I'm expecting to block the click action until the translation is complete.
I can't find a function which detects the current translation to do that :
" As long as a (transform) translation is in progress, prevent the click ".
$(document).on('click','.theyear, .themonth, .theday, .thehour, .themin',function(e){
   $window_position = parseInt($(document).find('#selector').css('transform').split(',')[4]);
   $date_selector_size = 300; // width
   if($window_position == 0){
      $val_slide = -($window_position + $date_selector_size);  
   }else if ($window_position > $size_window){
      $val_slide = ($window_position - $date_selector_size);     
   } 
   $(document).find('#selector').css('transform','translate('+$val_slide+'px)');
});
$(document).on('click','.bm .fa-arrow-left',function(e){
   if ($window_position < 0){
      $val_slide = ($window_position + $date_selector_size); 
   }
   $(document).find('#selector').css('transform','translate('+$val_slide+'px)');
});

